# Change Android API

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have written an app for Android 6(API 23).

My problem is that there is a way that I prepare my program for Android 4?

I want prepare my program for Android 4.thanks

I have build gradle file :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHl1O.png)

Comment: No, you have declared that your app can run safely on Android 2.3 (minSdkVersion) and newer and it's not using any new features above Android 4.3 (targetSdkVersion). [Learn the difference between targetSdkVersion, minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion.](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd) Test your application on Android versions from 2.3 (API 9) to 4.3 (API 18). After that you might even want to raise the targetSdkVersion to something higher.

Comment: Next time please copy formatted code directly into your question.

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create multiple apks for different versions,have a look at this:
[Creating Multiple APKs for Different API Levels](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html)

And for your question,  single apk to support different api levels:
[Supporting multiple API levels](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#ApiLevelOptions)

please read the documentation carefully before applying any changes..!